# Show escaped html tags from XML as well as non-escaped tags in XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, escaping, value-of

I have these escaped tags in my XML file: `&lt;strong&gt;` --> The whole xml is like this:

```
<test>
<TEST2>
     <li>&lt;strong&gt;blablablabla</li>
</TEST2>
<test>
```

I want to show the text in **strong and bold letters (like this)** and I want to show the list-item bullet. Now I only manage to show the text in strong and bold letters OR I can show the list-item bullet, but I never managed to show them both correctly. So my question is: how can I show them both in the right manner?

First, I tried `<xsl:value-of select="/test/TEST2" disable-output-escaping="yes" />`, which showed me the text in italic and bold version, but then, it did not output the list item bullets, because it just outputted the raw `<li>` tag...

Then, I tried `<xsl:copy-of-select="/test/TEST">`, which showed the list bullets, but this time, it also outputted the raw `<strong> and <em>` tags.

Besides, copy-of select, combined with `disable-output-escaping` did not work.

What should I do to show them both correctly?

**Sample outputs:**

`*<em><strong>blalblblbal</strong></em>` if I use the second one.

If I use the first one:

***blalblblbal***

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and a sample output document.

Comment: Of course I can: done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well use

```
<xsl:template match="li">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

of course with other templates for ancestors of `li` generating a `ol` or `ul` as needed and processing child elements e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="test">
  <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

But disable-output-escaping is not supported for instance for client-side XSLT in Mozilla browsers. And generally XSLT processors do not need to support it.